# CSS Clearing Table Borders

Tags: php, html, css, border, css-tables

Any ideas, how to make table look like this (marked with red circles) that there are no border and background color?

[image]

Comment: give `border-spacing:value`

Comment: that is not border-spacing, because then the space goes to all <td>'s, but I need only for the first two <td>'s and all rows

Answer (score 0):

```
table
{
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:10px 50px;
}
```

or whatever you want your spacing to be

Comment: like I already said: "that is not border-spacing, because then the space goes to all <td>'s, but I need only for the first two <td>'s and all rows"

Comment: @TomsBugna then why not make two separate tables, one with border spacing and one without?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `td`s some padding?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw8hU/)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more rows -->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr td:nth-of-type(2){
  padding:0 20px;
}
```